# geopandas "overlay" query is very slow?

Tags: geopandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using geopandas in a Jupyter notebook, working on OSX. I have imported a couple of shapefiles and transformed their CRSs, without any problems. The shapefiles aren't huge - one of the raw `.shp` files is 30MB, the other is less than 1MB.

I want to use geopandas to calculate the area of the overlap between them, but when I use `overlay` to start doing this:

```
df_sussex = gpd.overlay(df_sussex, df_sac, how='intersection')
```

the Jupyter notebook just hangs. It's been running for over an hour. There are no errors in the console, and the Activity monitor shows it's taking up 98% of CPU. I'm working on a machine with 16GB of RAM - surely it shouldn't take this long? In PostGIS on the same machine it just takes a few seconds.

Is there any way I can debug what's going on?

Both of the dataframes are in EPSG:4326, so I wonder if it could possibly be related to [this geopandas issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/400).

Comment: After some time, the notebook shows a warning: `site-packages/geopandas/base.py:75: UserWarning: Cannot generate spatial index: Missing package rtree.` Perhaps this is connected?

Comment: It is 100% connected. An intersection is an expensive task, and without a spatial index it is going to be a very slow.

Comment: Thanks. Even with an index though, it's still incredibly slow.

Answer (score -1):

i take an intersection between a 7000 polygons shapefile and a point using geopandas.overlay,it takes 2.3 second, then i do this in the mongodb ,create the geometry index, the intersection opration only takes 0.01 second.